# Creating a distance matrix in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

**X** is a Tensor("stack:0", shape=(10, 2), dtype=int32) that represents a matrix of coordinates like:

[[2, 1], [5, 5], [4, 1], [0, 0], [6, 1], [2, 4], [6, 3], [5, 2], [5, 0], [2, 2]]

I want to create a Euclidean Distance Matrix from **X** showing the distance between all coordinates pairs so I get a resulting Tensor with shape=(10, 10) like:

```
[[0.000  2.000  5.000  4.123  1.414  1.414  6.082   2.000  4.123  4.000]

 [2.000  0.000  4.123  4.123  1.414  3.162  6.708   2.828  2.236  4.472]

 [5.000  4.123  0.000  2.000  3.605  5.000  4.472   3.605  3.162  3.000]

 [4.123  4.123  2.000  0.000  3.000  3.605  2.828   2.236  4.242  1.000]

 [1.414  1.414  3.605  3.000  0.000  2.000  5.385   1.414  3.000  3.162]

 [1.414  3.162  5.000  3.605  2.000  0.000  5.000   1.414  5.000  3.162]

 [6.082  6.708  4.472  2.828  5.385  5.000  0.000   4.123  7.071  2.236]

 [2.000  2.828  3.605  2.236  1.414  1.414  4.123   0.000  4.123  2.000]

 [4.123  2.236  3.162  4.242  3.000  5.000  7.071   4.123  0.000  5.000]

 [4.000  4.472  3.000  1.000  3.162  3.162  2.236   2.000  5.000  0.000]]
```

I tried to use  **tf.norm**  (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm) but this function isn't working properly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a direct calculation of a matrix of euclidean distances in TF:

```
t0 = [[2, 1], [5, 5], [4, 1], [0, 0], [6, 1], [2, 4], [6, 3], [5, 2], [5, 0], [2, 2]]
t = tf.convert_to_tensor(t0, dtype=tf.float32)
```

create 2 helper Tensors with extra dimension. When substracted they will give pairwise differences

```
t1 = tf.reshape(t, (1,10,2))
t2 = tf.reshape(t, (10,1,2))

result = tf.norm(t1-t2, ord='euclidean', axis=2,)
```

result:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=157, shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.       , 5.       , 2.       , 2.236068 , 4.       , 3.       ,
        4.472136 , 3.1622777, 3.1622777, 1.       ],
       [5.       , 0.       , 4.1231055, 7.071068 , 4.1231055, 3.1622777,
        2.236068 , 3.       , 5.       , 4.2426405],
       [2.       , 4.1231055, 0.       , 4.1231055, 2.       , 3.6055512,
        2.828427 , 1.4142135, 1.4142135, 2.236068 ],
       [2.236068 , 7.071068 , 4.1231055, 0.       , 6.0827627, 4.472136 ,
        6.708204 , 5.3851647, 5.       , 2.828427 ],
       [4.       , 4.1231055, 2.       , 6.0827627, 0.       , 5.       ,
        2.       , 1.4142135, 1.4142135, 4.1231055],
       [3.       , 3.1622777, 3.6055512, 4.472136 , 5.       , 0.       ,
        4.1231055, 3.6055512, 5.       , 2.       ],
       [4.472136 , 2.236068 , 2.828427 , 6.708204 , 2.       , 4.1231055,
        0.       , 1.4142135, 3.1622777, 4.1231055],
       [3.1622777, 3.       , 1.4142135, 5.3851647, 1.4142135, 3.6055512,
        1.4142135, 0.       , 2.       , 3.       ],
       [3.1622777, 5.       , 1.4142135, 5.       , 1.4142135, 5.       ,
        3.1622777, 2.       , 0.       , 3.6055512],
       [1.       , 4.2426405, 2.236068 , 2.828427 , 4.1231055, 2.       ,
        4.1231055, 3.       , 3.6055512, 0.       ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: How do I change the result shape from (10, 10) to (?, 10, 10, 1)?
I would like to change the result shape to input it for a Flatten layer, whose input shape is (?, 10, 10, 1).

Comment: `result = tf.reshape (sometensor, (-1, 10, 10, 1))` but you may want to remove that Flatten layer instead

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works well for small inputs, it will get you in trouble if you have a large batch size, many dimensions or your input matrix is large for some other reason.

In the general case we have 2 input matrices `X` and `Y` (in OPs case `X==Y'`). The goal is to get the distance matrix `D`:

```py
D[i,j] = tf.norm(X[i, ...]-Y[..., j])
```

If `X.shape() == (a,b)` and `Y.shape() == (b,c)`, doing

```py
tf.norm(tf.reshape(X, (a,b,1)) - tf.reshape(Y, (1,b,c)), axis=1)
```

needs an intermediate matrix of size `(a,b,c)` which might not fit in memory.

In that case you can do some algebra to see that

```py
D == tf.sqrt(
    tf.maximum(0., # catch O(1e-9) round off error resulting in nans
        tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(X, 2), axis=-1, keepdims=True) + # (a, 1)
        tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(Y, 2), axis=-2, keepdims=True) - # (1, c)
        2*tf.matmul(X, Y) # (a, c)
    )
)
```

And this only makes a couple of matrices of size `(a,c)`. There is a little loss of precision which you have to catch to prevent taking the square root of a negative number.